# ListView custom selector not working

Tags: android, listview, selector, drawable

I'm currently trying to apply a selector for when the listview is hovered. When it is hovered, focussed or pressed it needs to turn grey. So i've been searching trough a few posts here on stack, but they all don't seem to be working.

My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hover" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hover" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hover" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

My listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/supplier_scan_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:divider="#eaeaea"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
    android:overScrollFooter="@android:color/transparent">
```

My custom list item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/order_count"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="$Artikelnaam"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scan_title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="$ArtikelDetail"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/order_count"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square_recent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the background of your list_item to the selector?

Comment: Yes, through xml and programmatically.

Comment: What's in your drawable/hover? Wouldn't it be easier to just pass the color gray in your selector?

Comment: Got it working, see the solution of mine

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your listview:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Neither working. That's the whole problem, every possible way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

This listview used a custom adapter (BaseAdapter). In this adapter I made the rootview an onClick, however this canceled my listSelector. So I changed it to an onItemClick on the ListView and made an extra method to return the information needed from my Adapter. By doing this the listSelector worked again.